# Real time video WinRT

Tags: video, windows-runtime, streaming

I'm building a Windows 8.1 Store App and I need to find a way to achieve "real-time" display of video. The situation is basically that I have several moving webcams, that are sending video to server and I need to find the best possible way how the server could expose the video so that it could be displayed on the client tablet with minimum possible latency (the client tablet will be used to control the moving camera, so the operator needs to see it as real time as possible). What protocols and approaches can be used in this case?

I want to note that I have little knowledge about this concrete field, so for this reason, the question is probably not as descriptive. I have searched for many things, but nothing helped (probably because I don't know what precisely I should search for).

Thank you very much

Comment: This seems to broad as you haven't attempted anything and is more design related.

Comment: Basically in this case I have the problem that I don't know where to start. If you can point me to some keywords to look for, some basic concept that is usually applied here, I will do the research needed. Just so far my searches haven't found anything, that could help me reach this "starting point"...

Comment: What's the "video server"? You have few details in your question. Is it code you wrote? What codecs are being used by the cameras? How are they "sending"? What type of connection would the client use? Wifi? Cell?

Comment: The server side is not maintained by me. I'm now writing a client app for the service, and my current task is to find a suitable protocol that will be supported on Windows Store client and the server-side developer will implement according endpoint for it. The client will connect to this endpoint via wifi.

Comment: Still -- too broad of a question. Search around for codecs supported in a WinRT application on MSDN. Have a look at http://playerframework.codeplex.com/ too.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look around and get back here in case I find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we have ended up with using WebSockets to stream the video, because we required just a low resolution and this approach was quite sufficient for this and offered almost real-time transmission.